# JavaScript scoping and function declaration

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to understand why inside the test() function, var g = f is not var g = f(). The output for alert(test(true)) is ['local', 'local'] vs ['global'] for alert(test(false)), so var g = f must be a declaration setting g equal to the outer f() function.

```
function f() { return "global";}

function test(x){

  var g = f, result = [];

  if(x){
    g = function(){return "local";};

    result.push(g());
  }
  result.push(g());
  return result;

}

alert(test(false));
```

Comment: Yes, `var g = f` is exactly that.  It makes the local variable `g` be an alias for the global function `f` and it remains that unless you reassign `g` to be something else in your `if` statement.  Which part of this is confusing to you?

Comment: var g = f; // g is a variable that has type is function. g(); // call function

Comment: If you write `var g = f()`, g will have the value returned by the function f but when you write `var g = f`, g  and f point to the same function object.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'm confused as to why isn't var g = f() with the '()', thanks for the help!

Comment: You can store/pass around functions as variables in JavaScript

Comment: Because you didn't write `var g = f()`.  You wrote `var g = f;`  What you wrote just assigns `g` to be an alias for `f` - it doesn't execute `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var g = f` gets a reference to the global function `f`, and stores that reference in `g`.

`var g = f()` calls `f` with no arguments, and stores whatever it returns in `g`.

If you replaced `var g = f` with `var g = f()` in your function, then `g` would start out containing a string, not a function. This isn't a problem when `x` is a truthy value, since in this case, you immediately reassign `g` to a function anyway. But if `x` is falsy, then you skip down to the line where you call `g`, only you can't call it, because it's a string instead of a function.

The confusing thing is notation. **When we aren't coding, it's common to write function names with a trailing () after them, to signify that they're functions. But we can't do that in most programming languages, because if we did, the compiler would think we were trying to call the function**. That's what's happening here.